# Windows 10 Intel 520 Graphics Driver Fails

Tags: windows-10, drivers, intel-graphics

I recently bought a brand new laptop computer: Core i5-6200, Win10 10.0.10586, HP Pavilion L8V46AV. About daily the graphics driver reboots, it gives me an error message in the lower right of the screen, and effectively messing up whatever app I am working on. The error message says:

> Display driver stopped responding and has recovered 
>   Display driver Intel HD Graphics Drivers for
>   Windows 8 (R) stopped responding and has successfully recovered

The actual error log in system information says:

> Application Error Faulting application name: IntelCpHDCPSvc.exe

I am using the onboard graphics: Intel HD graphics 520. The driver version installed is 10.18.15.4281.

First I tried Windows update, it doesn't find anything.

Second, Intel has a [graphics update utility](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/25620/Intel-Graphics-Driver-for-Windows-7-8-1-10-15-40-6th-Gen-). It says the current version is 15.40.14.32.4352. However when I run this utility, it tells me that the graphics driver will not work with my computer. I don't understand this, it specifically says Intel HD Graphics 520 in the download. Is there some way to force it to take the update?

Third, there is an HP update utility. It didn't detect anything.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. First, why would a brand new intel iGPU not support Windows 10? Why did it come with what seems to be a Win8 driver? How do I fix it? Intel's Software is not detecting an update to the latest version.

Comment: ignore the wrong reply from ramhound. Win10 supports the GPU. Try my steps

Comment: I obviously looked up the wrong iGPU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the ZIP from The [Intel downloadcenter](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/25620/Intel-Graphics-Driver-for-Windows-7-8-1-10-15-40-6th-Gen-) and now extract the zip.

Now [update the driver in device manager](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/9695-driver-install-device-manager-windows-8-a.html) to bypass the setup:

- start device manager
- select device and click on update driver
- Click on `Browse my computer for drivers software`
- Click on `Browse`
- Navigate to and select the folder that contains the driver for this device, and click on `OK`
- Click on `next` to install the driver:

[image: List item]

Comment: I did this.  It tells me that my drivers are already up to date despite being v10 instead of v15. When that didn't work I right clicked and uninstalled the 520 drivers, then manually installed the v15 drivers using the exe file from the same site. That gave me this error `This computer does not meet the minimum requirements of installing the software.`

Comment: Not sure how this happened, but I uninstalled the v10 drivers, and they automagically reinstalled twice. The third time it called the ersatz drivers, Microsoft Generic Display. I installed the new drivers using the above method. Device Manager now says my driver version is 20.19.15.4352.

Comment: ok, so now you use the latest driver revision 4352?

Comment: I did get these drivers installed. However, there are a few problems. In Firefox the screen constantly tears and doesn't seem to refresh correctly. Playing 1080P content in VLC, the computer doesn't keep up. I had an i5-4xxx laptop that seemed way more responsive than this i5-6200. Should I wait for new drivers? Any other ideas on stuff to install?

Comment: try to tuen HW acceleration in VLC and firefox off and look if this fixes it.

Comment: also try this older driver: https://downloadmirror.intel.com/25484/eng/win64_154010.4300.exe HP advices users to try this old driver.

Comment: I installed this driver. It went back to crashing. About once every two hours. Also when not in full screen mode there is a strange halo effect on objects in VLC player. I'm going to see if I can still return the computer. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: the HD 5xx seam to have a lot of driver issues. The 4364 can be found here: http://driveroff.net/soft/videointel500nt/  http://www.gigabase.com/getfile/HXO91X.ykaF1Uc6I5dJw4wBB/Video-Intel-HD500-20.19.15.4364-NTx64.7z.html maybe this driver fixes the issues.

Comment: Hopefully a final comment. I recently updated the BIOS for my computer, and in conjunction with the newest Intel driver (I think 15.40.18.4380) the crazy problems with VLC media player and the crashing dissipated. However Firefox rendering still has occasional issues.

Comment: also try to disalbe HW acceleration in FF

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with My Dell Inspiron 13-7359 with the same graphics card. The driver provided by the vendor was a Windows 8 driver, so I uninstalled it, and installed the one from the Intel website (automatic detection of hardware).

This driver has it's own problems, including Firefox rendering issues, but at least it does not crash.